# About adjectives used as noun

Tags: nouns, nominalizations, zero-derivation

There are some adjectives like valuable and rich has used as a noun as
Riches
Valuables.
But the meaning of these adjectives used as a noun is different .
Is there any other adjectives are there which are used as nouns.
What is the meaning of those words

Comment: What do you mean “the meaning is different”?

Comment: There are so many adjectives that can be used as nouns that you can't expect this forum to provide a list. Mostly the meaning is 'a thing or person which/who is [adjective]. _Riches_ is slightly different - 'things which make their owner rich'.